# Make Webpack load a wrapper for a module instead of the module directly

Tags: webpack, requirejs

We use some modules that need to be configured, i. e. `accounting.js`. We want to centralize the configuration for those libraries and automatically load the configured library when it is imported somewhere.

So, when a script imports accounting via `import accounting from 'accounting';` we don't want webpack to load the library directly, but instead load the configured wrapper.

The configuration wrapper script looks something like this

```
import accounting from 'accounting';

accounting.settings = {
    currency: {
        symbol : "€",   // default currency symbol is '$'
        format: "%v %s", // controls output: %s = symbol, %v = value/number (can be object: see below)
        decimal : ",",  // decimal point separator
        thousand: ".",  // thousands separator
        precision : 2   // decimal places
    },
    number: {
        precision : 0,  // default precision on numbers is 0
        thousand: ".",
        decimal : ","
    }
};

export default accounting;
```

with a configured `resolve.alias` in `webpack.config.js`

```
// ...
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'accounting': source_dir + '/accounting.wrapper.js'
    }
}
// ...
```

The problem now is that accounting can't be loaded in the wrapper file. Neither by module name (as shown in my example above), nor by its full path inside the node_modules directory (`import accounting from 'accounting/accounting.js';`).

With RequireJs, you could define aliases per file. You could create one alias rule that applied to all files, which aliased the library to its wrapper. Then you could create another alias rule specific to the wrapper file, so accounting inside the wrapper file referenced to the actual library.

Is there something similar in webpack?

### EDIT

By adding a `$` to the end of my alias definition, I was now able to load the actual library inside the wrapper script by using its full path inside the node_modules directory (`accounting/accounting.js`).

```
alias: {
    'accounting$': // ...
}
```

Still, this is not the same as what was possible in RequireJS.

Answer (score 0):

Since imports act as singletons and should return the same object everywhere, did you try to import the module and set `accounting.settings` before the module is used in the app?

Anyway, to wrap a module with webpack, I'd check [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/):

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
            /^accounting$/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/accounting-wrapper.js'),
        ),
    ],
};
```

In the wrapper, load the original module like this:

```
import accounting from '../path/to/node_modules/accounting';
```